# Apriori Not enough memory

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am using R and I use the following command and I get the error `not enough memory. Increase minimum support!` I tried increasing the support to 0.5 but I am still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated. My data is (5000,2).

```
> x=apriori(d,parameter = list(support=0.5,confidence=0.8,maxlen=5))

Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen maxlen target   ext
        0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5     0.3      1      5  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 0 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[2856 item(s), 2 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [2856 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 3 done [183.38s].
writing ... Error in apriori(d, parameter = list(support = 0.3, confidence = 0.8,  : 
  not enough memory. Increase minimum support!
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In asMethod(object) : removing duplicated items in transactions
2: In apriori(d, parameter = list(support = 0.3, confidence = 0.8,  :
  Mining stopped (time limit reached). Only patterns up to a length of 3 returned!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than 2 transactions. Association rule mining is typically used on thousands of transactions.